# Azure kubernetes deployment

Tags: azure

I have deployed my apps to a azure Kubernetes cluster. Whenever there is any change in any apps I create a new docker image and push it to a azure container registry in the respective repository. Right now I am manually copying image from the azure container registry and updating the image in YAML file. Is there a way that all deployment picks the latest pushed image from azure container registry?

BTW I have 3 deployments in AKS and 3 repositories in ACR.

**for example**

Deployments Repositories

abc abc_repo

def def_repo

fgh fgh_repo

Whenever a new image is pushed to abc_repo, then abc use that latest image for deployment.

Can I also configure YAML file in such a way that it uses the latest pushed image from repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters in your yaml file and use the BuildId to tag your docker images when pushing to ACR then the template will pull the image with the BuildId. Then you can track the image running on AKS from Code commit, Build Pipeline, to Release Pipeline.

Follow tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/aks-template?view=azure-devops)!